# Autofilter Each Criteria into Mail Merger with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Looking to combine these functions from a table that has a list of customer open orders and their email addresses by using an auto filter that cycles through each of the values in column F. The Mail merge portion of the script works fine but I would like it to repeat for each value in F. Any help would be appreciated!

Mail Merge script, A1 is where the sheet currently just stores a test email address but the column where all other email addresses are in a practical use is in column F so Ideally below script would just be either "the selected criteria" or whatever email addresses is showing in the top row -1 of column F (below the header) after the filter is applied.

```
   Sub esendtable()
    Dim outlook As Object
    Dim newEmail As Object
     Dim xInspect As Object
    Dim pageEditor As Object
    Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set newEmail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    With newEmail
    .To = Sheet1.Range("A1").Text
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Data"
    .Body = "Please find the requested information" & vbCrLf & "Best Regards"
    .display
    Set xInspect = newEmail.GetInspector
    Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor
    'Sheet1.Range("B2:E5").Copy
    Sheet1.Range("Table1[#All]").Copy
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
    .display
    '.Send
    Set pageEditor = Nothing
    Set xInspect = Nothing
End With
Set newEmail = Nothing
Set outlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Sample script I found online that loops through criteria that may useful in order to repeat the above function for each possible value in column F

```
    Sub LoopEachName()
      Dim aNames As Variant, Itm As Variant
  
      With Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
            aNames = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlVisible).Value
            For Each Itm In aNames
              .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Itm
      
              'Do whatever you want with an individual name here
      
        Next Itm
        .AutoFilter
      End With
   End Sub
```